# Actionscript PNGEncoder performance and UI blocking

Tags: apache-flex, flash, multithreading, actionscript

I'm trying to use PNGEncoder to encode a bitmapData object into a png ByteArray so I can send the data to the server.  Everything would be peachy except the bitmapData is 4000x4000px and when I run the PNGEncoder.encode function on it the whole app stops (UI is blocked) for 5-8 seconds while it runs.  Does anybody have any suggestions on how to not make it block so bad, I read about chunking up the process (since you can't multithread in AS3) but can't find any sample code on chunking up the process.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are mainly two ways to do this.

a) Use pixel bender:
You can off load the work to pixel bender (a shade like language in as3). This has the advantage of using the gpu on some cases, but it also is assynchronous and non blocking (runs on another thread). But it does require player 10+. I haven't seen a pixel bender png encoder, and to be honest, it may not be possible (I am not familiar enough with png encoding to tell), but it might be an option. This is, performance wise, the best you can get. More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Pixel_Bender)

b) Use chuncking. Basically, you rewrite the encoder to encode blocks (lines, columns or a smaller area), and hook that to an enter frame event, each frame you'd call next on your encoder, until there is no more encoding to do. Zeh has a neat [LWZ chunked encoder](http://labs.zeh.com.br/blog/?page_id=97) with source code that might give you insights into the details.

Cheers
Arthur

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Arthur's comment, you could also write it in C/C++ for [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/), since alchemy supports green threads. Like PixelBender, Alchemy also requires Flash 10.

Comment: Actually the libpng(in C, I think) is included as a sample when you download Alchemy.

Answer (score 1):

Another shameless plug!

You can use my recently completed PNGEncoder2 library (also requires Flash 10+), which handily supports gigantic images. It does proper asynchronous encoding, with no single compression step at the end. Additionally, it's really fast ;-)

Grab it from GitHub ([README](https://github.com/cameron314/PNGEncoder2/#readme)), and check out the [benchmark](http://moodycamel.com/blog/2011/a-better-png-encoder-for-flash#results) comparing it with other encoders on my blog post.

It's highly tuned for speed, and uses the Alchemy opcodes and [domain memory](http://ncannasse.fr/blog/virtual_memory_api) to speed it up (thanks to [Haxe](http://haxe.org/)), so it should be comparable to anything you compile using Alchemy.

Comment: Very nice! Is this faster, than async JPEG encoders like http://segfaultlabs.com/devlogs/alchemy-asynchronous-jpeg-encoding-2 ?

Comment: @sydd: Thanks! I have no idea how fast that JPEG encoder is; you'd have to run a benchmark to find out (shouldn't be too hard to throw one together though). Keep in mind that JPEG is a completely different format from PNG; JPEG will likely result in much smaller file sizes, but can't encode the alpha channel, etc. Also be aware that it's very tricky to get asynchronous encoding to be fast in Flash (at least, it's hard to get it *consistently* fast across disparate systems and loads while maintaining a frame rate) -- so test the sync versions separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could encode multiple PNG files separately and send them to the server. Once on the server you can reconstruct the larger image.

Comment: I mulled that over but in this particular use case thats not an option :(

Answer (score 0):

It's for JPEG encoding, but should be useful - look a this post http://segfaultlabs.com/blog/post/asynchronous-jpeg-encoding/

Answer (score 0):

As Arthur Debert said, you can use chunking. I'd suggest that instead of encoding once/frame, you try a `setTimeout( chunkingFunction, 0 );` approach. A timeout with a 0 ms delay will happen as soon as possible, allowing the chunking to process quickly but without crushing the UI.